# How to map the source object of type String to target UUID in MapStruct?

Tags: java, mapstruct, mapper

Here is a code snippet:

**Source:**

```
public class BuyerInfo {
   String membershipID;
}
```

**Target:**

```
public class BuyerInfo {
   UUID membershipID;
}
```

**Error in console:**

Can't map property "String buyerInfo.primaryMembershipID" to "UUID buyerInfo.id". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "UUID map(String value)".

Comment: And what is it you don't understand? Declare a method that maps from a `String` to a `UUID`.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, but how. Even if i declare it with @Named() it is not working.

Comment: I think the error message itself is pretty self-explanatory. Did you try to go through MapStruct [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/) or some [articles](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct-custom-mapper)

Comment: You already have a mapper (class anotated with `@Mapper`) just add that method in there.

Comment: Which version of MapStruct are you using, recent versions should support this out-of-the-box (IIRC).

Comment: I am using 1.5.2 version

Comment: Are you sure that is the version you are using? As it was added in 1.5.0 (one of the miltestones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked for me.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface SourceToTargetMapper {

    SourceToTargetMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( SourceToTargetMapper.class );

    @Mapping(target="buyerInfo.id", expression = "java(mapToBuyerInfoId(buyerMetaData))")
    Order sourceOrderList(SourceOrder.Order sourceOrder);

    default UUID mapToBuyerInfoId(BuyerMetaData buyerInfo){
        return UUID.fromString(buyerInfo.getPrimaryMembershipID());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should make a `UUID map(String)` method instead. That way you don't need to use a java expression but can just use `source` and `target`.

Comment: I tried but it is not working. also it is an interface. i can only write default methods

Comment: So write a default method that takes that signature. Nonetheless MapStruct 1.5 should support this out-of-the-box so I wonder how you defined your mapper.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you post it as an answer. The answer which is posted is the mapper class.

Comment: The mapper is as I written a `String` input to `UUID`. You only need to change the signature of your method. And I don't know what you have written in your current `@Mapper` as source and target (or your initial one). But as stated it should work out-of-the-box with 1..5.2 so I suspect it is your own `@Mapper` definition that is wrong.